# Generate data to get required covariance matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to generate data based on the following conditions with 100 observations. Here `e` is disturbance term. Any help?

I am struck at creating disturbance terms for `x3, x4, x5`.

```r
x1 = N(0, 1)
x2 = N(0, 1)
x3 = 0.5*x1 + 0.5*x2 + 0.5*e3
x4 = 0.5*x3 + 0.707*e4
x5 = 0.5*x3 + 0.707*e5

cov(e4, e5) = 0.5
```

Required output:

```r
     x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
x1 0.931
x2 0.171 1.094
x3 0.630 0.762 1.350
x4 0.384 0.368 0.743 1.265
x5 0.324 0.385 0.611 0.624 0.949
```

Comment: This sounds like a typical problem for a mathematical statistics course. I suspect it’s easily found if you use Google or search the SE forum on Statistics.

Comment: Generating data that has a pre-specified covariants structure is not trivial.  Take a look at the [mvtnorm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html).

Comment: Looking again at this it appears somewhat confusing. Seeing x3, x4, and x5 defined as a sums that includes themselves make it appear to be a correlated multi variable  time series. (That wasn’t clear to me at first glance. ) Perhaps you need to more clearly define the problem if you post it to stats.SE.